# Hide all but one match, which is shown, in one jquery line

Tags: jquery, hide, show

There seem to be many answers on SO to hide all but one element of a selector, e.g.

```
$('li').not('.shown').hide()
```

but this does not explicitly `show()` the element `<li class="shown">` if it has been hidden previously. To deal with this, other SO answers suggest a 2 liner, which has the disadvantage of hiding all the elements first, then showing one, which may cause flicker:

```
$('li').hide()
$('li.shown').show()
```

Is there a jQuery syntax which I can use which does this in a single loop? I'm not sure whether e.g.

```
$('li').hide().filter('.shown').show()
```

will do this, or whether that simply does the same as the 2 liner, looping first over all the matches, then later switching one back on again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the two by using `$.not('.shown')` or `:not(.shown)` when you hide the `li`'s, then use `$.end()` and use `$.filter('.shown').show()`

```js
$('li').not('.shown').hide().end().filter('.shown').show();
```

```css
.shown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>asdf</li>
<li>foo</li>
<li class="shown">show</li>
<li>bar</li>
```

Comment: Thanks. So is this optimised by jQuery so that the `.shown` element is not first hidden, then shown again? How can I test the underlying jQuery algorithm? It certainly seems like there should be enough information in the syntax for the intention to be clear. [edit - sorry, of course, the 'not' does that. Doh.]

Comment: Seems a little ugly to have to repeat the refining filter ('.shown') twice - there's nothing build-in, I guess.

Comment: are all of these in the same list? as in, are they siblings? or could they be anywhere on the page in different parents?

Comment: Could be anywhere in the page. I want this to be general. It seems like I want something like `end()` but which selects the elements previously filtered out. A sort of `.invert_last()` selector. I can't see anything like this in the docs.

Comment: It does get somewhat convoluted with the repeated syntax. For instance, I now seem to have code that looks like this rather unmaintainable chain (I'm showing selected text within a box that is itself sometimes hidden): `$('.closeable').not(#boxContainer,#aboutBox).hide().end().filter('#boxContainer,#aboutBox').show().find('.hideable').not('#htmltext_how').hide().end().filter('#htmltext_how').show();`

Comment: Well what I wrote above could also be written as this without any sort of flicker `$('li').show().filter(':not(.shown)').hide();`

Comment: Thanks. Does that not flicker in the sense that everything gets shown then all but one hidden? I should say that most of the `<li>` elements will be hidden most of the time, so showing them all at once, if only briefly, might give weird effects.

Comment: would there be `li`'s that are hidden already? I'm just working with the code from your OP. This would flicker any `li`'s that are currently hidden and don't have class `.shown`.

Comment: If you're just concerned with repeating code (like a DRY thing), you could make the elements you're repeating (like `.shown`) a variable, then just reference the var in your commands.

Comment: Yes, it seems nicer as a function: `function showonly(selector, to_show) { return selector.not(to_show).hide().end().filter(to_show).show();}`, which then means I can do e.g. `showonly(showonly($('.closeable'),'#boxContainer,#aboutBox').find​('.hideable'),'#textToShow')`, which is clearer. So thanks a lot for your help. Slightly surprised that there isn't something build-in in jQuery, though.